# Issue with Java generics syntax

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to make a list of Entry and having trouble on how to do this. Not sure if it is even possible, but I'm trying to have the Example object return the V of the entry it finds. I don't want it to return just an 'Object'. Yes, it gives compile errors for the get() method but how would I fix it so it works? Thanks.
Each entry may have different types.

```
public class Example {

private List<Entry<?>> data = new ArrayList<Entry<?>>();

public Example() {

}

public V get(String path) {
    for (Entry<?> entry : data) {
        if (entry.getPath().equals(path)) {
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static class Entry<V> {

    private String path;
    private V value;

    public Entry() {

    }

    public Entry(String path, V value) {
        this.path = path;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    private V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please show us your compile errors.

Comment: The error is 'public V get(String path)' of course but my question is how would I make it recognize V?

Comment: What if you do `private List<Entry<V>> data = new ArrayList<Entry<V>>();` like that?

Comment: If I use V anywhere in the Entry class it asks to add <V> to Example, that I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

You may not want to make `Example` generic, but that's what you need to do, since you want to store generic `Entry` objects and have `get(String)` return a generic object:

```
public class Example<T> {

    private List<Entry<T>> data = new ArrayList<Entry<T>>();

    public Example() {

    }

    public T get(String path) {
        for (Entry<T> entry : data) {
            if (entry.getPath().equals(path)) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static class Entry<V> {
        . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can't have a list of different possible V? and have It return what ever it is.

Comment: @CBennett - Since an instance of `Example` has to store a list of `Entry` objects, and `Entry` is generic, you are kind of stuck. The alternative would be to make `Entry` non-generic and store `Object` instances for its value. You would then give up all the compile-time type checking that generics provides. Perhaps you can explain what you're trying to accomplish in more detail and we could suggest another approach.

Comment: My goal is to have the example class as a holder list of multiple entry<V> that may be Entry<String>, Entry<Integer>, or anything, all not the same. Then to have the example method get() return the Type of the entry's value. Like if its a Entry<String> it returns a string, etc.

Comment: @CBennett - If you intend for a single instance of `Example` to hold `Entry<V>` objects for multiple types `V`, that's pretty much impossible because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Since `V` is unbound in your code, after compilation, all occurrences of `V` are replaced by `Object` in the bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of `V` when calling `get(String)` then you can add a `Class` parameter to cast the content of `Entry<?>` to the type you want :

```
public <V> V get(String path, Class<V> clazz) {
    for (Entry<?> entry : data) {
        if (entry.getPath().equals(path) && clazz.isInstance(entry.getValue())) {
            return clazz.cast(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is how to use it :

```
example.add(new Entry<String>("color", "blue"));
example.add(new Entry<String>("model", "Some Model"));
example.add(new Entry<Integer>("numberOfTires", 4));

Integer tires = example.get("age", Integer.class);
String model = example.get("model", String.class);
```

And by the way, maybe you should use a `Map` instead of iterating on a list of path.

Comment: Thank you this works! Didn't know you could add generic types to methods, nice.